# Enable CORS on ASP.NET Core 7.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I am trying to deploy an app that has the frontend hosted on a different server than the backend. The back is hosted on a Windows server, which uses ISS.

My frontend is in React and fetch my API using these headers :

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

I need to enable and configure CORS to be able to do API requests on the backend. My backend is developed using ASP.NET Core 7.0.

I followed [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on how to enable CORS with .net core 7.0 but this doesn't seem to work. Every fetch call from my frontend ends up with:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Here is my backend `Program.cs` file :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                policy =>
                  {
                      string[] origins = { "https://myfrontendurl.fr" };

                      policy.WithOrigins(origins)
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                  });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

It seems to me that everything is configured how it should be, but nothing I tried really worked.

I also tried adding a custom response header in IIS, but it doesn't seem to work either, generating a new error:

[image]

I get this error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://myfrontendurl.fr, https://myfrontendurl.fr', but only one is allowed

which is weird considering it doesn't have a single one when I don't add it in IIS, and now it has too much.

As a comment suggested, I looked into `IIS CORS module` thinking it was maybe the solution, but on the [home page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) it says that IIS CORS Module is designed so that `developers can move CORS logic out of their applications and rely on the web server` and that's not what I want. I want my app to be able to manage CORS by itself.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: My guess would be that the header is not forwarded by IIS if you don't setup it in this way. I'm not IIS expert so I can only recommend to check IIS logs and see info about IIS CORS module - https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: try removing the iis header since you are already setting the allow origin header in the code. make sure that the `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` is called **before** `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints()` or `app.MapControllers()` in your middleware pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @JalpaPanchal, I already removed the header from IIS as it did not managed to solve the issue. For the order we don't use `app.UseRouting()` or `app.UseEndpoints()` and my `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` is already before `app.MapControllers()` so I'm not sure that the problem is here

Comment: Can you, for 100% clarity, post the browser URL when you try to connect?

Comment: don't set those headers in front-end.  (not the problem here, but you should be aware that the server responds with those headers via <options> verb to browser's preflight request...)

Comment: @gaeljoliveau BTW try adding explicit `app.UseRouting()` before `app.UseCors();`

Comment: Going into IIS log we noticed that the http verb used was <options> thanks to you @pcalkins we could understand why and removed theese headers from the frontend. We also managed to track donwn the error and solve the issue. I'll write a proper answer to explain how we corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your comments that helped us find the issue.

Looking into ISS logs, we found that our routes were called using the `OPTIONS` http verb, even with the frontend explicitly using `GET` or `POST`.

We removed the headers from the front as a comment suggested and could get back to our original http verbs. We also had a new error message in the frontend console, which was a `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

From there, we looked at what http error codes our backend could send, and we discovered that it was designed in a way that never responds with error codes and never catching exceptions.
We also found that our production server database was moved to another server and that the production environment had not been updated. With our backend design, it could only go wrong.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>> Get()
{

    if (_connexionStringDB != null) 
    { 
        return Ok(ItemProvider.GetItems(_connexionStringDB));
    }
    return Ok(new List<Item>());
}
```

We changed the configuration so that it had the new database address, and our http requests started working again.

I think what happened is that the SQL request failed and threw an exception that was never caught and was somehow handled by IIS or the system. This response did not have the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as it was not generated by our backend app. This would explain why we had the CORS message even though the backend app was configured properly.

I am immediately changing the backend architecture so that it can handle exceptions and return a proper `500 error` in the event of an exception.

I'm a bit embarrassed to admit it, but it's a beginner mistake to not catch exceptions in the backend and handle them by responding with a proper HTTP response code. I hope that this post will help someone avoid being in the same situation.